# On which DNA strand is TATA box present?

Tags: molecular-biology, transcription

My book (Snustard and Simmons) mentions that TATA box is present on the non-coding DNA strand but that was for the promoter of mouse thymidine kinase gene.

I have tried to find out more information and stumbled upon these in wikipedia articles which actually said something else:

> The TATA box can be an AT-rich sequence "located at a fixed distance upstream of the **transcription start site**. (from a paper "The RNA Polymerase II Core Promoter'')

Then (from a book: *Understanding bioinformatics*),

> The Transcription start site is the location where transcription starts at the 5'-end of a gene sequence.

So my question is, on which strand is TATA box actually (or generally) present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TATA box is a feature of organisms that have dsDNA as a genetic material. Like most dsDNA promoter elements, TATA box is basically a section of dsDNA.

However a question like "On which DNA strand is TATA box present?" depends on what you define TATA-box as.

If you go by [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TATA_box):

> In molecular biology, the TATA box (also called the Goldberg-Hogness
>   box)<sup>[2]</sup> is a DNA sequence (cis-regulatory element) found in the
>   promoter region of genes in archaea and eukaryotes

then TATA-box is merely a DNA sequence and is just a representation of a ssDNA region. However, TATA-box is also the binding site for TBP (TATA-binding protein; part of the TFIID complex). While the recognition of DNA elements by the TFs is effectuated by the interaction of amino acid residues with DNA bases and backbone [on  one or both the strands](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/38873/3340), the TF binding and its activity has a stereochemistry.

Likewise, TBP also interacts with bases as well as the sugar-phosphate backbone on both the strands ([Juo et al., 1996](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jmbi.1996.0456); [PDB:1TGH](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore.do?structureId=1TGH)).

> [image]
>
> [image]
>   <sub>**Figure 2**. Stereo pair drawings of the human TBP/DNA complex, with TBP at right and the sharply bent C-G-T-A-T-A-T-A-T-A-C-G duplex at left. (a) Molscript skeletal drawing (Kraulis, 1991). TBP residues that interact with the floor of the minor groove are shown in red with one-letter amino acid codes, and residues that interact with the sugar/phosphate backbone are shown in green. **The coding strand of DNA is dark blue**, and the **non-coding strand is light blue**. The two yellow-green base-pairs at bottom are the T1-A2 step that is kinked by interstitial phenylalanine residues, while the equivalent kinked step at T7-A8 is marked in orange. (b) Secondary structure diagram, with a-helices as coils and b-sheet strands as flat ribbon arrows pointing along N-to-C chain direction. Color coding as in (a).</sub>

Considering this, you can say that TATA-box is essentially a dsDNA region.

However, another twist in the story is that TBP can also activate genes with TATA-less promoters ([Kamenova et al., 2014](https://dx.doi.org/10.1128%2FMCB.01685-13)) and this is possibly facilitated by other protein partners of TBP in TFIID complex.

> Our results are consistent with the model that sequence-specific
>   TBP-DNA contacts are not important at yeast TATA-less genes and
>   suggest that other general transcription factors or coactivator
>   subunits are responsible for recognition of TATA-less promoters. Our
>   results also explain why yeast TBP derivatives defective for TATA
>   binding appear defective in activated transcription.

This, still does not contradict with the fact that TATA-promoters need TBP and the binding is on both the strands.

So, my conclusion is that **TATA-box is a dsDNA element** but has a polarity in its mode of action.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably too late, but that's what I found in a book:

''Also, by convention, the DNA regulatory sequence elements (TATA box, etc) are described in the 5′ to 3′ direction and as being on the coding strand.''

Reference: Harper’s Illustrated Biochemistry, twenty-sixth edition,  Chapter 37 RNA SYNTHESIS, PROCESSING, & MODIFICATION, page 345, Figure 37–5.

Comment: Its never too late to answer a question ;)